# Object-C Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I'm very new to Object-C programming and got an assignment. While building , the build failed with linker error due to duplicate symbols. I did my own analysis seems like it broke because , in one of the class file we have this :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return kCellHeight;
}
```

And in another class we have this:

```
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width-10,kCellHeight - 5);
```

where as the kCellHeight has been defined in an interface as :

```
NSInteger const kCellHeight = 100;
```

Is that correct analysis?

Development Env:

XCode: 7.3.1
Target SDK : 7.1

Thanks in advance..
-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps (although it would be easier to tell if you gave the compiler error). I assume that when you say "`kCellHeight` has been defined in an interface" you mean in a header file? Constants should be *declared* in a header file, but *defined* in an implementation file. Like this:

```
/* in .h file */
extern const NSInteger kCellHeight;

/* in .m file */
const NSInteger kCellHeight = 100;
```

If defined in a header file, `kCellHeight` will be defined whenever that header file is imported, which will result in multiple definitions (and a linker error).

Comment: yes , I want to mean interface as .h and class as .m file. Now going back to your point , I dont see the declaration in the .m files. I will try in a few mins. and share my findings. Thanks @mipadi.

Comment: @sahaS: You only need the definition in *one* `.m` file.